# Date picker in kendo JS is displaying as textbox

Tags: jquery

Am using below cshtml code to populate date picker in View.

```
<input class="form-control " data-role="datepicker" id="ActualDateID"
data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" placeholder="[DD/MM/YYYY]"
data-type="date" name="dtActualDate"
/>
```

But in view this control is displaying as Text box.
Please suggest solution for this...

Note: below code is working

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("datepicker"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the similar issue with MVC5 and Telerik 2016. Adding...

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")

in _Layout.cshtml in head section resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following **Code**. And if you want to add more configuration,please visit this [page](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker)

**UPDATE::**

**HTML**

```
   <input id="datePicker" />
   <input id="datePicker2" />
```

**JS**

```
$("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
    close: function() {
       console.log("closed datePicker");   
    }
});

var two = $("#datePicker2");

two.kendoDatePicker({});

two.data("kendoDatePicker").bind("close", function() {
   console.log("closed datePicker2"); 
});
```

Also see the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4dA9/250/)

> Note : Kendojs datepicker is available for [PHP](http://demos.telerik.com/php-ui/datepicker/index),[JSP](http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/datepicker/index) AND [ASP.NET MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/index).